# How top user percentage for a period is calculated

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

When I view any profile I see that the user is *top 5% this quarter* or *top 0.3% this year*. Clicking on that link takes me to the page where I can see the week / month / quarter / year / overall rank.

What calculations are done to find this percentage?

Comment: Rank everyone's reputation from highest to lowest, then determine what % bracket he falls in?

Comment: https://stackapps.com/q/7661 - Check this.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The value is determined as follows:

- For each of the rankings, take your position, then convert that position to a percentage for *all* users that are ranked (only users with 200 points or more and with a positive reputation change in that period are listed in the rankings, see the last page of a ranking to see how many users are listed).
- The *highest percentage* is then shown on your profile, rounded up to a sensible number.

For example, you are currently placed at #8086 this quarter. There are (so far) 169,875 users with 200 points or more and a positive reputation change listed in this quarters ranking, so that ranks you in the top 4.76% this quarter. That is your highest percentage across the leagues and is rounded up to 5% when displayed in your profile.

If you rank in the top 1%, the rounding adjusts to show 1 decimal point; those in the top 0.1% get two decimal points of precision. That means that even Jon Skeet will forever be listed as *top 0.01% overall* even though he is the top 0.0004795% percent, really.

Comment: Is this formula still accurate? Specifically the last section regarding rounding. Currently my profile says `top 0.71% this month`, so I would have thought the _"top 1%, the rounding adjusts to show 1 decimal point"_ rule would have rounded it to simply `0.7%`.

Comment: @Madness: I don't know; I haven't paid attention to the numbers much (and I am ranked too high to see anything other than `0.01%`).

Comment: @Madness: does it matter that much though? If the number is rounded to 1 or 2 decimals after the decimal point?

Comment: Not really, I was just hoping to keep my calculations in line with Stack's

Comment: @Madness: it could be that between `1.0` and `0.1` you get two decimals too and I simply missed that detail last time, or that it has been updated in the meantime to show that much more detail.

Comment: Are these rules true of the global reputation ranking or the tag-specific ones as well? The developer story lists a user's top tags, say, _top 5% in Java_.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz: developer story ranks are calculated differently; I believe they only take into account *accounts with a developer story*.

Comment: There is something that doesn't work for me. I'm actually top 4% of the month. My procedure is very close to the steps you suggested, before reading your answer. Month rank: #7328, users with 200+ reputation: 439894. If I do maths on this: 7328/439894*100 I would be top 1.66%, say 2% which is half of the value. Is the gap due to the fact that not all the 439894 users have a positive reputation change? how to establish the total userbase with 200+ reputation AND positive reputation change? my problem was solved by [this tool](https://rankoverflow.philnet.ch/) but what's the maths behind?

Comment: @Antonino: There are 204399 ranked users with 200+ reputation and a reputation *change*, just go to the last page of the monthly ranking using the page numbers at the bottom of the page. 7328/204399*100 is 3.585%, rounded to 4%.

Comment: ciao @MartijnPieters, thanks for replying! as per my answer below I understood this point but I didn't understand why that number [the last user on the last page] is actually different from the stats in the tables reported below. So are you suggesting that 204399 is the amount of those 400K+ users which have more than 200 points AND had a change [positive or negative] in the stats in this month? in other words: there are no users among those 204399 that have a reputation change equal to +0, right? thanks a lot for your message and have a good day!

Comment: @Antonino: everyone with at least 200 points of rep during that month, *and* a reputation change (so no +0 entries) are listed. There are 400k people with 200 rep or more, but only a bit over 200k saw a reputation change. That includes negative changes.

Answer (score 1):

The users of the site are ranked in reputation gained over that period of time, and the user's absolute rank can be divided by the total number of users to get their rank as a percentage.