# What is "top % this quarter" based on?

Tags: support, statistics

Let me first say that this is a not an important issue. More a curious wondering how this works, and why my chosen stat seems so off (to me).

If I look at my profile I'm greeted with the below screen, where it states that I'm *top 0,47% this quarter*. When I look around at other profiles it might say that they're, for example, *top 51% overall*.

[image]

It just doesn't make sense to why the system has chosen to display my itsy-bitsy 0,47%, while someone not-that-active is shown 51% overall.

Is it based on *total rep over the course of a quarter* (for all users)? If so I could see how I can be top 0,47%. I still don't understand why the system displays this, and why others get overall (or something else).

Comment: Probably just a simple "find the best-looking stat (highest percentile)" and display that.  And quarterly stats are like financial quarters so anything from April 1 to now.

Comment: Sounds to me like you interpreting it backwards, "Top %" means that 99.53% of the SO users got less rep than you did.  You are supposed to feel good about belonging to the 0.47% elite.

Comment: Oh, now I'm really embarrassed. I totally missed that @HansPassant. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Related to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280036/how-top-user-percentage-for-a-period-is-calculated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is based on how much rep you have gained in that period of time. If you click on this stat, you will be taken to your place in that particular user league.

> [image]

As you can see, the last column is the amount of rep you have gained for that period of time, which is how these leagues are ordered. The "change" column indicates how many places you've changed since the last time interval- The "all time" league does not have this column.

At the top of the page, you can switch which league you are looking at.

> [image]

There are multiple leagues for this: week, month, quarter, year, and all time. It's based on how much rep you have gained for the amount of time each league is for.

For this quarter, you are in the top 0.47% of users based on the amount of rep you have earned in this quarter alone, meaning you have earned more rep in this quarter than 99.53% of the tracked users. Your friend has more total rep than 49% of the users tracked in the leagues. Note that only users with at least 200 reputation points are tracked in the league. If all users were tracked, your friend would be even farther up in the leagues despite a low reputation.

As far as I can tell, the message there displays the league that you're highest in- For you, it's currently the quarter. For your friend, it's all time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would this make my friend, top 51% overall with his ~650 rep though?

Comment: @Mackan Simple: There are a lot of users, and overall he has more rep than ~50% of the ones tracked in the leagues. The default display setting in the league page is 30 users per page. All time, there are 7699 pages, and that's just users with at least 200 rep.

Comment: Bah, it all makes sense .. and I don't like it! ;) I thought it would be based on some complex algoritm of views, people reached and favorite food.

Comment: @Mackan When everything else is a complicated algorithm, it's easy to expect that. ;) I added a little bit more explanation to flesh out the answer better. Feel free to go and browse the reputation leagues! It can be a fun little time waster to see where in all you stand.

Comment: Thanks for a very informative answer! The cause of my confusion was that I interpreted 0,47% as *in the lower percentile*. The fact that I could mix up 'top', considdering I previously had a good database-guy-career (before this post that is), makes this extra painful ;)