# Can someone be a "top user" if they haven't been active for 2 years?

Tags: feature-request

For the first time ever, I downvoted an answer and left a comment - the answer was simply, numerically incorrect. After weeks, [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2570347/privatehuff) has not replied, so I looked at their Profile... 1 Question, 2 Answers, and: they have not been seen in over 2 years. Yet at the top it says "Top 29% overall". Leaving aside how someone could be in the top third with so little participation, why is any sort of calculation done on their rank if they are apparently not participating anymore?

To simplify the question: shouldn't standing only be displayed for people who have **at least visited the site** within the past year? "Emeritus" users don't need to appear in the current stats.

I see that I made a mistake in my reading of the thing in the Answer that I thought was incorrect. I have acknowledged that. Not sure if I can rescind downvote. Still not clear how someone can be a Top x% Overall if they are not here anymore...

Another point (added later): If my comments go to a user who is not active, how can they respond or I get any feedback about the point in question? There is not curation of Answers where a user is no longer active.

**Update:** On the Buddhism SE, when I look at a user, it says something more clear, like "top 10% this year". Why does that site include a timeframe when the other site does not?

**Update to Update:** I see that if someone has not been active for a year, it says "Overall". If they have been active in this past year, it says, "This Year". That is understandable, but I don't like things that slide around and reformulate. My experience has mostly been on a site (Buddhism) that is recent and so everyone I encountered was active recently. I never "logged" the wording per se, I just read it. So when the meaning changed, I was thrown. I don't like things like this. Ribbon anyone?

Comment: What would be the advantage of this? Those rankings have **no** impact on the site functionality.

Comment: If he's in the 29% of all time for rep, why should we not show it?

Comment: Because they're still _getting and losing reputation_ could be one reason. That ranking is entirely based on reputation. (This is ignoring the fact that, as mentioned, the rankings have _zero_ impact on anything.)

Comment: _"not an "All Time" scoreboard."_ See, there's your disconnect. The "Overall" section _is_ the all-time scoreboard. That user is probably ranked much lower in the Quarter/Month/Week leagues.

Comment: I'm looking for something more concrete, but a couple of my answers may help you better understand the rep leagues. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294098/what-is-top-this-quarter-based-on/294105#294105) and [here.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303327/why-does-giving-a-bounty-reduce-your-ranking-on-so/303330#303330)

Comment: Just pointing out that if you click on the "top 29% overall", it sends you to his alltime rank and rep... I think "all time" is pretty clear, no?

Comment: I am just looking at the ordinary User profile page, and that is what it says. The user basically has one answer with 100 upvotes (less my downvote because the answer is actually incorrect). How does this make someone a "Top User" by any definition? There are bound to be more than 35 profile vies soon though. 15 minutes of fame for you!

Comment: The ordinary user profile page _doesn't use_ the term "rank", so what are you objecting to? It just [says "top NN% overall"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vba11.png). You don't see the word "rank" until you click through to the league listing, where [it's joined by the words "all time"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KHv6T.png).

Comment: But again, "he IS in the top 29% overall". In no way does "29% overall" implies ANYTHING but "29% overall". I don't see how come you think there should be a time based thing to an overall rating....

Comment: Right, I introduced the word "rank" and took it out. Sorry. My point stands, that someone who is not active cannot be a Top User. That is ridiculous.

Comment: WHY? He has 10 times your rep (not a complaint about you, just an observation that, numerically, his OVERALL rating is higher than yours). Whether he's active or not is irrelevant. If Jon Skeet left for 3 years, he'd still be THE TOP SO USER. why should we take that away?

Comment: Someone who isn't active can't have more rep than any number of people on the site? That's all the "Top" means there. You came here to raise a point that it's not right, but you don't seem to have tried to figure out what it meant first. If Jon Skeet quit using SO tomorrow and never returned, would he no longer count as the user with more rep than anyone on the site? His account would still exist and still have that rep, after all.

Comment: And to be honest, that is why I downvoted your post- No research effort. You don't in any way appear to have tried to understand how the system works before saying it doesn't, in this case.

Comment: *"Emeritus" users don't need to appear in the current stats* - They do if the statistic is based solely on reputation.

Comment: How can someone who is no longer active have any reputation? As I have read, the concept of rep is that you can rely on someone's answers. If they are not here anymore, there is no one there to rely on.

Comment: Their answers are still on this site, to be relied upon. Their account is still there, and still has reputation associated with it. If the answers get to the point they are no longer correct in any way, they will likely be downvoted, the account will begin to lose rep, and things will begin to align the way you're advocating here.

Comment: *As I have read, the concept of rep is that you can rely on someone's answers.* - Where did you read that? That is not what reputation means. Reputation is a measure of how much the site trusts you.

Comment: Are you relying on the person or their answers? Because their answers are still there.

Comment: I have seen too many old answers that were incorrect. If someone is not current, then to me, their work is discredited. Time Marches On.

Comment: That's a myopic view.

Comment: @Patrice: the answer is wrong, so it should have no rep associated with it. But that is not my beef. I only wondered why this person has not responded to my comment. Because they are not here anymore.

Comment: then if it's wrong, downvote it. I fail to see how the ranking has to do anything with this

Comment: The answer isn't even wrong. Go read the comment after yours.

Comment: ... funny how we were all just talking about Skeet and he shows up on the answer :p

Comment: @nocomprende and HOW would you show something is wrong for posterity? By downvoting my friend. If the answer really is wrong, over time, enough downvotes will pop on it that it won't be worth points. Now, you are against it, 100 users are for it... Stack is community moderated website. Not saying you are wrong (I didn't really look at the Q&A pair enough to make a judgement), but so far the community seems one sided

Comment: I see that I made a mistake in my reading of the thing I thought was incorrect. So, it is correct. I guess people who no longer participate can be "Top x% Overall" too, although it seems strangely wrong to me.

Comment: I suppose that will be the end of downvoting, and meta posts.

Comment: @nocomprende again, the top % is for the overall, all time rep and contributions to the site. Look at Alex Martelli's profile. He was inactive for what? A good year or two IIRC. Is it fair to remove the fact that he is one of the best answerers on the website? I really don't think so(votes on meta don't cost anything, so don't fret... and why would you stop coming to meta? not like we attacked you....)

Comment: How much do you want me to participate every day before you start deleting my old, highly-voted content on the assumption that it's probably bitrotted and no longer applicable? Do I need to answer a question every day, even if there are no new good ones I can add anything helpful to?

Comment: @Wooble I wouldn't delete anything, but if I comment on your posts and you are no longer here to answer, then that defeats an important part of the site. If you are not a participant, say at least monthly, then you cannot respond to anything that happens. So you are not here. Responsibility for your posts should devolve to someone else.

Comment: _"There is not curation of Answers where a user is no longer active."_ Yes there is. Anyone can suggest edits to improve answers. Anyone over 2k has their edits applied automatically. Anyone over 125 rep can downvote answers that can't be corrected, and once they're negative, said answers can even be deleted. The original answerer is not the only one who can maintain even a non-wiki answer. Just look at this case: You commented, and someone else commented how you were incorrect. It didn't have to be the original answerer who answered you.

Comment: @Kendra OK, but nothing happened until I protested. I did the only things I could: downvote, then post on Meta (over a different issue). It turns out that I was wrong about my original issue, which is fine, but I didn't see that until someone responded. I have created a lot of fuss over nothing, all because the original user was no longer reachable. In a Wiki, someone would have responded sooner, and properly. I don't see why people should "own" their posts, not if they can take their ball and go home. When you leave, they no longer belong to you, but to the community, which must manage them.

Comment: It's an _old_ post, it may take people time to see it. That's going to happen. We have _over 10 million questions_ on this site, and even more answers! And people can't exactly "take their ball and go home" by just stopping coming to the site. The user went home, but the ball is still sitting right there. You came up, noticed the ball, and said, "Hey, that ball isn't right. There's a problem with that ball." And you reacted accordingly. So you were wrong this time. Even if you weren't, you reacted within your powers to the ball.

Comment: @nocomprende if you want real-time interaction use chat.  Posts and comments have no guarantee that anyone will interact with them.

Comment: And let me part from this discussion with this: Even if a user is active an online every day, you may not get a response from them on your given point. They have every right to actively ignore whatever you say on their post, even if you downvote it. Hell, even if half the active community downvotes it, there is no requirement that they answer you. So that point isn't really helping you make your case here.

Comment: @Kendra OK. But it makes my point that content that someone is not responsible for is not valid content. It is not "live" and not reliable. This would never fly in a business context.

Comment: Now perhaps everyone can un-downvote because I have done the research, which no one else did in answering me. I figured out what was going on, but nobody could explain it.

Comment: No, you still haven't quite figured it out, but you're really close and on the right track! This was actually explained in [one of the answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294098/what-is-top-this-quarter-based-on/294105#294105) I linked you to previously- Your profile shows the rep league you're currently highest in. Since that user isn't active, and therefore isn't actively gaining a whole lot of rep, his current highest standing in any of the leagues is in the "All Time" league. This is represented in the profile with "Overall" instead, probably for conciseness.

Comment: OK @Kendra, I hadn't read your Top Quarter post because that wasn't what I was looking at, but it does explain what I discovered. I am still struggling with 2 things: 1) the stat on the profile page changes with context, and I didn't notice, 2) I am confused by a system which both associates content with the providing user, and has users long inactive. This looks exactly like a link rot problem to me. It is either the user's content, or it isn't. anything that has been "vetted" and accepted should morph over to community wiki, as I see it. I am told this isn't a community, but it has "people"?

Comment: And I hadn't even thought of "favorite food". I guess I will start a new feature request about that.

Comment: I think part of the problem is you're putting waaaaaaay more value into the rep leagues, which are just a "for fun" list of who's gained the most rep in one of several time ranges, than they were ever meant to have. Of course the content is associated with the providing user- How fair will it be if a user's been unable to access the internet for a year (say they had some massive health issue and have been in a hospital for most of that time) and come back to find that all of their turned into community wiki even though it was fine and didn't need to be edited by the community. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Which would inevitably happen if we just auto-morphed content to community wiki after some time. It used to be that if a question or answer was edited so many times, even if by the author, it would be automatically converted to community wiki. That wasn't fair to the authors, however, as a number of them that had this happen had it happen because a) the question was edited frequently and converted, which auto-converted all answers as well, or b) they were editing to make their answer the best it could be and because of that got it auto-converted.

Comment: Auto-converting after a set amount of "vetting" and time would have similar issues- What if that user is still active? Suddenly they aren't allowed to gain rep for their answer? If that's turned on for questions, a user who posts a new, better answer might not get _any_ rep for it. That'd be discouraging. If an answer is being maintained by the community, it can be converted manually to community wiki. If it's not being edited frequently by the community and kept up-to-date through that means, it's kinda unfair to the author to convert it to community wiki.

Comment: @Kendra I wasn't paying attention to rep. I made a comment on an answer, nothing happened for a while, so I clicked on their profile. I saw Top 29%, and then saw last active 2 years ago. Those two pieces of data clashed. It was cognitive dissonance. If you saw a car on a lot that said, "top 29% sold" and last sold 2 years ago, that would be strange to you, right? The car then belongs in a museum, not on the lot.

Comment: (Last one, promise! Not trying to spam you!) The content belongs tot he user, even if they're inactive, until the community is frequently editing it to maintain. Then it's appropriate to call it community wiki. We don't penalize users for being inactive- They could decide to return at any time. At the same time, all content is community content, even if it's not a wiki post. This is because the community can edit it, and the community can decide if those edits are appropriate. But occasional edits to fix formatting and such don't make that content not that of the original author.

Comment: _"If you saw a car on a lot that said, "top 29% sold" and last sold 2 years ago, that would be strange to you, right?"_ No, actually, I would just assume that the car sold _really amazingly well_ before it's last sale, and that kept it in the top 29%. Which is what this is. The user just has more rep than 71% of users above 200 rep. That's all that's telling you. That's all that's ever meant to tell you. You're reading a lot more into it than was ever intended.

Comment: *Ribbon anyone?* What?

Comment: @BSMP: the reference is to the Ribbon method of organizing the MS Office product menus. Having context-sensitive tabs appear and disappear is bad enough, but having options show or not based on how wide the screen is and what exactly is happening is maddening. Some famous person (can't refind the reference right now, Bret Victor mentioned him) went on a quest to eliminate "modes" from software. This is what I am talking about. Each control should do one and only one thing, and either work, or be greyed out. "More than this comes of evil."

Answer (score 22):

The top percentile number does not mean a wholeheckofalot, you get to be in the 50% percentile with only 21 rep.  A side effect of SO having so many users that never contribute anything.

But he did, he earned most of his rep (~990) with an answer he posted 7 years ago.  The Q+A is *canonical* and ranks as the top Google hit for anybody that queries "what is a race condition?".  His answer was viewed about 200,000 times.  Perhaps the reason you found it in the first place.

This is the kind of Q+A that is strongly pursued as a goal of SO, both by its founders and its site members.  It can be extraordinarily helpful to anybody that has the same or similar question.  And everybody else, the question will never have to be asked again.  That a contributor continues to earn reputation from a post that's proven to be reputable is entirely by design.

And there is no obvious reason to assume that the post will diminish in value any time soon.  If you see a need for an update or correction then you can edit the post.  Or propose an edit if you don't have enough rep.

Comment: I didn't know about editing someone's answer, or proposing an edit. I commented, and after a while, nothing happened. It was then that I saw the person was not active. So, I didn't know how they could answer questions or make corrections. This is why I think a wiki is better: someone is curating.

Comment: If the Top % is now meaningless. perhaps it should not be so prominent in the User Profile? I think that Last Seen should be the most prominent thing there.

Comment: I think top% is a fun stat to have. last seen isn't that interesting, because i can care less *who* posted the content; anyone on the site can suggest changes to it. We don't need the original author to keep the post up to date.

Comment: Buddhism SE says something like: "top 10% this year". More clear, in my opinion.

Comment: ... or post a competing answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the reputation of only the people who have been active in the past year,  you can create a query in the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new).

Comment: You can fork one of mine and produce something that will work: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268067/158100

Comment: I just looked at what was shown on the User Profile. Nothing told me that it was clickable with other stats available. I just assumed that if it was right there in big letters at the top, that it would have a commonsense meaning. To me, a lapsed user cannot be in the Top anything. They are gone.

Comment: *Nothing told me that it was clickable* @nocomprende - The stat text is in a button, similar to the "Questions, Tags, Users..." navigation at the top of the page. Most text in a box and/or colored background is going to be a link.

Comment: *that it would have a commonsense meaning.* - @nocomprende - I get that you disagree with the SO engineers and community about what the number should mean. It doesn't look like there's anything either side can do about that though.

Comment: Buddhism SE says something like: "top 10% this year". More clear, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

User profiles display their percentile rank based on the best ranking available between several different time periods: current week, month, quarter, year, and all time. No preference is given to longer periods, so if those are even slightly less favorable, they won't be shown. The ranking displayed always includes the time period.

From this we can deduce that it's a minor ego-boosting frill on a user's profile, showing them in (more or less) their best light as far as reputation distributions go. That's all.

I don't really know why someone's past efforts should be discounted simply because they're no longer active, but in any case, it should be fairly clear if someone's profile is resting on its laurels, since it will fall back to the Overall ranking. Anyone that has anything else is almost certainly still going strong. And, of course, if you look at the leaderboards (linked in the rank displayed on the profile, as well as from the Users page), which is the logical place to go if you're really serious about respecting only those who are actively helping the site *right this second*, the views will only include those within a given time period.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what is going on now that I poked around a bit. And all the descriptions by many people in the know are great. The point was, it was a lot of hidden functionality that I knew nothing about. What was on the surface appeared very much simpler, and I didn't give it any thought. When complex things are hidden behind a simple facade, it opens the door to people getting very confused. New users who just jump in and get started can get thrown by things changing that they didn't know about. For this reason, I have always preferred simple programs, languages and interfaces.