# Top x% this {time period}. How is the time period chosen?

Tags: support, top-users, time

On my profile I usually have a mention of the type

> Top x% this {time period}.

where x is a number between 1 and 99 (supposidely) and {time period} is something like `month` or `year` or maybe even `week`.

The time period keeps changing all the time. How is this time period chosen?
Is it good when all of a sudden I passed from being top 20% this year to top 20% this month?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280036/how-top-user-percentage-for-a-period-is-calculated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Why does the "top X%" in my profile change frequently between week/month/all time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92328/why-does-the-top-x-in-my-profile-change-frequently-between-week-month-all-tim)

> The metric reported on your profile under the big score is your best overall percentage ranking in the leagues over the most recent time periods that are collected and reported.