# Calculate Year Rank in percent via data.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, data-explorer

According to this answer on Meta your ranking value is determined by these factors:

- Take your position, then convert that position to a percentage for *all* users that qualify (only users with 200 points or more and with a positive reputation change in that period are listed in the rankings).
- The *highest percentage* is then shown on your profile, rounded up to a sensible number.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280038/3850405

There is also a nice answer on data.stackexchange.com calculating rank and percentile:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6772/stackoverflow-rank-and-percentile

However this answer only counts users with a reputation above 100 so perhaps this was the previous requirements, the query was created in 2010.

I have edited the query to only include users with 200 points or above and I think this query gives the correct result for year rank.

The query shows me a rank of `32130` with a reputation of `4007` and on reputation league `all time` my rank shows as `31895` with all time reputation of `4,042`. Current reputation is `4,047` so I guess this has something to do with update frequency. Is this a correct guess?

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/679737/stackoverflow-rank-and-percentile?UserId=3850405

[image]

[image]

What I can't solve however is to calculate year rank via data.stackexchange.com. Is this possible to do? The problem as you can see is that the user object only has reputation as an integer and I can't find something else to base it on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SEDE is only updated weekly, on Sunday after 03:00 UTC.  This means that the data you looking at can be up to 7 days old.  It is good enough for a lot of thing but if you want to query stuff about right now(the present) then it is not going to work.