# Can I toggle the filter in my reputation ranking?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

There is a section of the Activity tab on my profile page that shows how I rank among other Stack Overflow users by a filter (month, year or quarter). These filters change from time to time. Currently, here's what is displayed:

[image: Example of reputation graph with reputation rank]

But right now, I want to see my percentage ranking this year, **not this quarter**. Is there any way I can toggle this? Is there any approach I can use to view it asides calculating it manually from [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/)?

Comment: no and you can calculate it without using the league, but that involves crunching the numbers across literally millions of users which you'll have to do using a massive data dump released four times a year (IIRC).

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350085/calculate-year-rank-in-percent-via-data-stackexchange-com