# Check what top% of the year/quarter/month/week I am in

Tags: discussion

I see "top x% of the quarter". How do I check my "top x% of the year"?

I've read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280038/5343790). I am aware of "The highest percentage is then shown on your profile, rounded up to a sensible number." Hence, quarter top is being shown. For fun, I would like to check what top% of the year/quarter/month/week I am in. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this post.

https://stackapps.com/questions/7661/rankoverflow-a-website-to-calculate-your-stack-overflow-reputation-rank-in-all

Visit https://rankoverflow.philnet.ch/